# Owncloud/Nginx on Arch - Site can't be reached

Tags: ssl, nginx, archlinux, raspberry-pi3, owncloud

I have installed the arch system on my raspberry pi 3. After the instalation i have followed this [guide](https://www.linuxbabe.com/cloud-storage/setup-owncloud-9-server-nginx-mariadb-php7-arch-linux) on how to configure the owncloud. For the SSl Certificate i have followed the instructions from the arch owncloud [documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nginx#TLS.2FSSL).

> etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
http{ 

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
  #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
  #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

  sendfile        on;
  #tcp_nopush     on;

  #keepalive_timeout  0;
  keepalive_timeout  65;

  #gzip  on;

  server {
     listen       80;
     server_name  localhost;

     #charset koi8-r;

     #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

     location / {
         root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
         index  index.html index.htm;
      }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht { 
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#    listen       8000;
#    listen       somename:8080;
#    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
 #}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#    listen       443 ssl;
#    server_name  localhost;

#    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

#    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
#    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
# }
}
```

> /etc/nginx/conf.d/owncloud.conf

```
 #upstream php-handler {
 #server 127.0.0.1:9000;
# server unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
#}

server {
 listen 80;
 server_name mycloud.go.com;
 # enforce https
 return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
 }

server {
 listen 443 ssl;
 server_name mycloud.go.com;

 ssl_certificate ssl/server.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key ssl/server.key;

# Add headers to serve security related headers
 add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
 add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
 add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
 add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
 add_header X-Robots-Tag none;

 # Path to the root of your installation
 root /usr/share/webapps/owncloud;
 # set max upload size
 client_max_body_size 10G;
 fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

 # Disable gzip to avoid the removal of the ETag header
 gzip off;

 # Uncomment if your server is build with the ngx_pagespeed module
 # This module is currently not supported.
 #pagespeed off;

 index index.php;
 error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
 error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;

 rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ permanent;
 rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ permanent;

 # The following 2 rules are only needed for the user_webfinger app.
 # Uncomment it if you're planning to use this app.
 #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
 #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

 location = /robots.txt {
 allow all;
 log_not_found off;
 access_log off;
 }

location ~ ^/(build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)/ {
   deny all;
}

location ~ ^/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
  deny all;
}

location / {
  rewrite ^/remote/(.*) /remote.php last;
  rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

 location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true; #Avoid sending the security headers twice
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
 }

 # Adding the cache control header for js and css files
 # Make sure it is BELOW the location ~ \.php(?:$|/) { block
 location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
 add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=7200";
 # Add headers to serve security related headers
 add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
 add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
 add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
 add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
 add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
 # Optional: Don't log access to assets
    access_log off;
   }

 # Optional: Don't log access to other assets
 location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|swf)$ {
   access_log off;
 }
}
```

And when I access the server name from my browser it gives me this:

> This site can’t be reached
>   mycloud.go.com refused to connect.

My ssl certificates are located in:

> /etc/nginx/ssl

Also after I check the syntax of owncloud.conf it gives me:

> 2016/08/19 14:03:02 [emerg] 1513#1513: "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/owncloud.conf:6
>   nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/owncloud.conf test failed

Comment: do you mean the /etc/php/php.ini?

Comment: Oh...owncloud use the php-fpm module so i think it might be also included

Comment: Does it give that error with the upstream commented out?

Comment: it gives me this: 2016/08/19 16:13:03 [emerg] 1746#1746: "upstream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/owncloud.conf:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what the problem was. I was setting the wrong port in my router. I was setting the 80 external port and it needed to be 443. Also here is my owncloud.conf which is working

```
server {

   listen             80;
   server_name        localhost;
   return             301 https://$server_name$request_uri;              
 }



server  {

    listen       443;
    ssl on;

    server_name  localhost;






    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';



# Add headers to serve security related headers
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Robots-Tag none;



 # Path to the root of your installation
 root /usr/share/webapps/owncloud;
 # set max upload size
 client_max_body_size 10G;
 fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

     # Disable gzip to avoid the removal of the ETag header
 gzip off;

 # Uncomment if your server is build with the ngx_pagespeed module
 # This module is currently not supported.
 #pagespeed off;        

 index index.php;
 error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
 error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;


     rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ permanent;
 rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ permanent;

 location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }

     location = /robots.txt {
     allow all;
     log_not_found off;
     access_log off;
}

location ~ ^/(build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)/ {
      deny all;
}

location ~ ^/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
    deny all;
}





    location / {
    rewrite ^/remote/(.*) /remote.php last;
    rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

    location ~ \.php(?:$|/)  {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;     
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }


 # Adding the cache control header for js and css files
 # Make sure it is BELOW the location ~ \.php(?:$|/) { block
 location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
 add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=7200";
 # Add headers to serve security related headers
 add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
 add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
     add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
 add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
 add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
 # Optional: Don't log access to assets
 access_log off;
}

# Optional: Don't log access to other assets
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|swf)$ {
access_log off;
}
}
```